# Turn on user logging in Hadoop

Tags: logging, hadoop, mapreduce

As far as I know Hadoop should log standard output and standard error from mappers and reducers in `${HADOOP_HOME}/logs/userlog/`, but this is not happening in my configuration.

I can't figure out, how do I turn logging on from mappers and reducers?

None of the printing methods work, like: `System.out.println("...")`, `System.err.println("...")` and `LOG.error("...")`.

Comment: I assume you are looking at the above dir on the data nodes themselves and not necessarily the box where you launched the job from. Also, can you access the job tracker for your cluster? Do you see them there? What hadoop distribution/version are you using?

Comment: Yes, I am looking on the nodes themselves. I managed to find the logs for standard output and error, but if I use log4j with a custom logger created by me, I can't see any output. Perhaps I need to configure this somehow in log4j.properties.